# Linearly Independent Vectors that span subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

If I have three vectors $v$1,$v$2,$v$2 that are linearly independent, is it true that there are no redundant vectors in the span ($v$1,$v$2,$v$2)?
I thought span meant the linear combination of vectors but my professor made the statement above about redundant vectors that baffled me.

Comment: If, by redundant, you mean a vector which can be written two different way using the spanning vectors, then:  if $\vec v=a\vec {v_1}+b\vec {v_2}+c\vec {v_3}= A\vec {v_1}+B\vec {v_2}+C\vec {v_3}$ then $\vec 0=(A-a)\vec {v_1}+(B-b)\vec {v_2}+(C-c)\vec {v_3}$ and since the three vectors are linearly independent...

Comment: So what are redundant vectors basically?

Comment: It's not a standard term.  I guessed that you meant any vector, $\vec v$ in my first comment, that can be written in (at least) two different ways using the given spanning vectors.  If your three spanning vectors were $(1,0), (1,1), (0,1)$ then $(1,1)$ would be redundant since it can be written as $\vec {v_2}$ or as $\vec {v_1}+\vec {v_3}$.  But, I repeat, I just guessed at what the word meant.  You should ask your instructor to confirm.

Comment: You wrote $v_1,v_2,v_2$, which would be linearly dependent.

Comment: I was giving an example to illustrate my definition of redundant.  As my first comment shows, there are no redundant vectors if the spanning set is linearly independent.